# Find minimum value in range after a maximum value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data structured as follows:
`A1:A8 (10, 2, 11, 15, 17, 10, 4, 5)`

I wish to find the SMALLEST value that occurs AFTER the LARGEST value. In the example above, it would be `4 or A7` and not `A2`.

I have tried to use the `DMIN` and a combination of `MIN` plus `IF` functions, but they all return the smallest value, not the smallest after the largest.

Thank you!

Comment: Any chance that there are multiple largest value? If so which one do you choose?

Comment: @DeanOC Good point! In my dataset, I am yet to see this. Although I would prefer the last occurrence of the largest value. I am after a peak value and the minimum value that occurs after the peak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=MIN(IF((MAX(IF(A1:A8=MAX(A1:A8),ROW(A1:A8)))<ROW(A1:A8))*A1:A8>0,A1:A8))
```

You will need to enter this with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**.